# Code: 1722, SQL State: 42000 ORA-01722: número no válido

Tags: sql

El siguiente query me aparece con este error

```
select s.solicitud, 
       s.concepto, 
       nvl(s.oficio, ' ') oficio, 
       t.descripcion tipo, 
       d.descripcion dependencia, 
       r.nombre_completo responsable 
       from solicitud s, 
            tipo_solicitud t, 
            dependencia d, 
            responsable r 
       where s.solicitud in (select solicitud 
                                    from solicitud_2_vw 
                                    where s.usuario='NHPONCE' 
                                          and estatus='A'
             ) 
             and s.tipo_solicitud = t.tipo_solicitud 
             and s.clasificacion = t.clasificacion 
             and s.dependencia = d.dependencia 
             and s.responsable = r.responsable 
       order by s.fecha_captura desc
```

ya revise los campos y no me aparece nada

Comment: Tienes algún tipo de conversión implícita de cae a número, yo revisaría el tipo de dato de `s.oficio` y `solicitud_2_vw.estatus`, son  cadenas realmente?

Comment: Ese error ocurre pq estas convirtiendo una cadena que no es número a número debes de chequear si la cadena que estás convirtiendo es solo numero

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo es un problema de tipo de dato, verifica bien los campos que deberían de botarte un numero. Me parece que quizás el campo **s.oficio** puede ser el que te de problemas, revísalo bien.